# The best way to plot General solution of differential equation in shape of Inverse Function

Tags: differential-equations

Differential equation which solve by separation of variables. 
$$ y'=\frac{x^3e^{3y}}{e^{2x}(4-y)^3} $$

```
sol=DSolve[y'[x] == (x^3 E^(3 y[x]))/(E^(2 x) (4 - y[x])^3), y[x], x]



 {{y[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     1/27 E^(-3 #1) (454 - 366 #1 + 99 #1^2 - 9 #1^3) &][
    1/8 E^(-2 x) (3 + 6 x + 6 x^2 + 4 x^3) + C[1]]}}
```

I know there are many posts of InverseFunction but i didnt find excactly how to plot this General Solution of d.e when I get it like InverseFunction .

If i try

```
 Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol /. C[1] -> Range[-3, 3]], {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> 10]
```

I get blank graphic.

Comment: These functions you're trying to plot are in general complex, so `Plot`ting them will not work.  In addition, I think you'll have to do something like `Block[{C}, Table[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {C[1], -3, 3}]]` instead of the replacement rule that you tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] == (x^3 E^(3 y[x]))/(E^(2 x) (4 - y[x])^3), y[x], 
    x][[1]];

Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Tooltip[
     y[x] /. sol /. C[1] -> #,
     #] & /@
   Range[0, 3]],
 {x, -1, 10},
 PlotRange -> {0, 2},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Green, Red},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Range[0, 3], {0.75, 0.75}],
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]